# better way to overwrite?

Tags: files

We are currently doing classic planA.

I want to know which one is better?

Both `fileA` and `fileB` exist, with size of ~50-100M.

assume in the same NFS mount in Linux/mac

assume this is a overwrite where both files exist

```
# planA - we do this way
mv /pathA/fileA /pathB/fileB

# planB
rm /pathB/fileB; mv /pathA/fileB /pathB/fileB

# planB1 - I think is the same as planB, but not sure
unlink /pathB/fileB; ln /pathA/fileA /pathB/fileB
```

Comment: i think simple renaming is the better and fast option. A

Comment: Can you even *do* hardlinks over NFS? (I don't have the environment to try it.)

Comment: Yes, we have done a lot of them just to save disk space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When it comes to file IO, the expensive task is moving the data around.

If it's within a filesystem (which it would have to be for that `ln` to work) the difference is moot.

In each case, all that's happening is a directory entry is getting modified to point to a different inode. That'll only be a negligible difference if best, so you're comparing 'how fast do commands start up' really.

But with one caveat - that *last* command will leave `/pathA/fileA` in place - it's a hard link, making both directory entries point to the same data.

This might confuse people in future, because if they *overwrite* fileA, it'll do one thing, and if they *edit* it it'll do something else.

So just err on the side of simple - stick with just an `mv`. It won't make much difference overall, and that's the most clear as to what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: If a `unlink /pathA/fileA` were added to 'Plan B1', all three operations would be practically equivalent.